# ASP.NET WCF REST Linq-to-SQL POST/WebInvoke JSON, Object with EntitySet generated by Linq-to-SQL

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, wcf, rest

So my problem is little bit complicated.

Main goal: register account (class / table) that contains list of Players (class / table) from a web application into a SQL Server database through a WCF service.

So for creating the classes I used Linq-to-SQL which created the `Account` and `Player` class. The `Player` has a foreign key `AccountEmail` to the `Account` table. Due to that the class `Account` has `EntitySet<Player> _Players;`.

Now the web application has reference to this service and when user finish registration I am making an POST request with `WebClient` and `DataContractJsonSerializer` to the service .

Unfortunately the service or the http protocol cannot understand the request :

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400)
>
> Full error response from server
>   https://s31.postimg.org/x6b27uqqj/errorrr.png

The fail is on service side for some reason it doesn't know how to read the json player `DB.designer.cs:line 295 at ReadPlayerFromJson(XmlReaderDelegator`

Service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Register", 
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
void RegisterAccount(Account account);
```

Client side :

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Account));

MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();

Account a = new Account { EMAIL = Email.Text, PASSWORD = Password.Text, NAME = nickname.Text};
a.Players = accountPLayers.ToArray();
ser.WriteObject(mem, a);

string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray(), 0, (int)mem.Length);

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
webClient.UploadString(WEB_SITE_URL+ "/Register", "POST", data);
```

When sending `Account` without the list of players, the operation succeeds:

```
{"EMAIL":"test@gmail.com","NAME":"1","PASSWORD":"test","Players":null}
```

With the list of players the operation fails :

```
 {"EMAIL":"test@gmail.com","NAME":"1","PASSWORD":"test","Players":[{"Account":null,"AccountEmail":"test@gmail.com","FirstName":"test","Id":0,"LastName":"test","Type":-1}]}
```

Questions:

1. I guess that REST service expecting to get only `Account` and doesn't know what is the list of players? I have to define that somehow.
2. Why in the service does the `Account` have `EntitySet<Player> _Players;`? And in the client after adding reference to service it is an array `Player[]` ?
3. Why does Linq-to-SQL add field `Account` to player? What should it contain? As you can see this field is null in the json.
4. Is complex object/known types has to do something with my problem ?

Please help me to solve this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !!!
So if any one ever will get this problem ,
The thing is that player has foreign key of EMAIL column to Account Email .
When you create your JSON  DO NOT PUT EMAIL INSIDE EACH PLAYER 
LINQTOSQL knows the association and will add it automatically when parsing the JSON .

So my JSON Sent to the service looks like this :

```
 {"EMAIL":"test@gmail.com","NAME":"test","PASSWORD":"test@A","Players":[{"Account":null,"AccountEmail":null,"FirstName":"wow","Id":0,"LastName":"koko","Type":null}]}.
```